# React Native: Log wrong responses

Tags: react-native, error-handling, fetch, xdebug

How can I log wrong responses in a fetch statement?
My code looks something like this:

```
eturn fetch('myurl.com', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData); // This logs nothing
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error " + error); // This logs something
        });
```

The log from my code example is `Error SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`. I think this is because of XDebug sending some error messages, but I have absolutly no Idea what might have gone wrong. It looks like the Response starts with '<', so I think it is a html tag.

Is it possible to show this response? That would be very useful to find my mistake.

Comment: for debugging remove the `.then((response) => response.json())` part, after debugging bring it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and be sure that url return correct json format:

```
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                data: res.data
            }, () => {
                console.log("log something")
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.setState({ loading:false, error });
        });
```

Comment: This is my Problem. I wan't to see what **exactly** url returns, because of I can't find any issue while debugging my PHP code behind the url. With your code I'm getting exactly the same error. `Error SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`

Comment: Well this means your url doesn't return json. Remove the first .then line and try again? and use data: res instead of data: res.data. If you are sure that your url return json then keep the first .then line and just do console.log(res)

Comment: I am pretty sure that url doesn't return correct json format. Please provide the url so we can help.